# Rabbitmq получать не все сообщения одновременно

Tags: java, rabbitmq

пишу на Java одно приложение. Оно состоит из нескольких отдельных программ, которые передают друг другу данные при помощи очередей в Rabbitmq. Я использую следующую конструкцию для получения сообщений:

```
channel.basicConsume("from_grabber", false, "",
                new DefaultConsumer(channel){
                    @Override
                    public void handleDelivery(String tag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[]body){
                        Обработка сообщения в отдельном потоке из Executors.newFixedThreadPool

                    }
                }
                );
```

Но Rabbitmq отправляет сразу же все сообщения, какие только может (какие содержатся в очереди). Можно ли изменить это поведение? Возможно ли настроить его так, чтобы он отправил n сообщений (где n заранее установленное число), затем подождал, пока хотя бы одно сообщение обработается и только после этого отправил новое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно настроить [Quality of Service (QoS)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html)

Для этого вызовите метод у канала: `channel.basicQos(n);`
Где N это количество сообщений, которое может находиться одновременно в обработке. 0 - без лимита, 1 - слать 1 сообщение клиенту и ждать подтверждения о завершении обработки, после чего пришлет следующее.